# Does VMware Workstation Update Timestamps on Unchanged VMDK Files?

Tags: backup, vmware, vmware-workstation, timestamp, file-history

I'm looking into solutions for backing up virtual machines and I was wondering if anyone can confirm how VMware Workstation handles timestamps on vmdk files.  If I'm using a vmdk drive split into multiple 2GB files will VMware workstation update the timestamp on all 2GB files or only on those that actually had data change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this out on VMware Workstation 15.5 using a small vmdk hard drive file split into 10 files it turns out only the changed vmdk files get their timestamp updated.  Any vmdk files that did not change keep their original modification timestamp.

Comment: That would depend on the extent of the changes. More changes (like an OS update that I do from time to time) would lead to more segment changes. Still, your question was about backup strategy and you  must backup the entire folder (all the segments and all the files)

Answer (score 0):

VMware Workstation will update the dates on all the file segments, and you need to back up all the segments - not just some. You also need the other files (vmx, nvram and so on).  You need to back up the entire folder for the machine and everything in the folde.